# Ignore margin from additional text in a button

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble with a `<button>` element wanting to move out of position when more than a single line of text is entered into it. Normally you would be able to work around this in a static design, however considering the text inside of the button is `dynamic` and will change depending on values in the database. It's posing an issue. Below is an example of what I'm talking about.

```css
body {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.col {
  width: 49%;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button">This button has too much text so it shrinks and overlaps the one below it. Instead I just want the text to fill up the button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button">Text</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button">Text</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button">Text</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it so the text will fill the button without applying a margin to the top? (I say margin, because in my project the size of the button does not change, however it just moves down and overlaps the other button. (See screenshot):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what you mean here – I can’t see anything actually “overlapping” something else in your example, and when you say the button *shrinks* when it gets *more* content, that doesn’t seem to make sense to me either.

So I can only *guess* that perhaps you simply want to specify the vertical alignment of elements of different heights properly …?

```css
body {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.col {
  width: 49%;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top; /* added just this, to align content */
                      /* of different heights to the top of those columns */
  
}

.button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button">This button has too much text so it shrinks and overlaps the one below it. Instead I just want the text to fill up the button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button">Text</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button">Text</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button">Text</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The alignment code provided fixed the issue in the project at hand, and fixed the overlapping issue. The overlapping is seen in the screenshot provided at the bottom of the question, the "shrinking" was present in the original snippet.

Comment: I couldn’t spot any shrinking or overlapping as in the screenshot in your example, when viewing your snippet in my browser … but anyway, if my suggestion fixed your issue, all’s good and well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `.col` styles from

`display: inline-block;`

to

`display: block; float:left;` :

Also you may want to change its width to 50%.

http://jsfiddle.net/2yt09g25/2/

```css
body {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.col {
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button">This button has too much text so it shrinks and overlaps the one below it. Instead I just want the text to fill up the button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button">Text</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button">Text</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button">Text</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, floating elements completely destroy the entire layout of the application. They also don't work the same across multiple browsers on mobile devices. (You'd think by 2015 browsers would be caught up)

Comment: Not sure about your layout, but they seems to work OK in all major (and not) browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=float%3Aleft